# Navigator 2.0 and Drawer

Tags: flutter

I use flutter's 2.0 navigation as described in the official example: https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade.
I extended this example and placed a drawer in the BookDetailsScreen. This drawer has a ListTile which calls _handleHome on BookRouterDelegate:

```
void _handleHome() {
    _selectedBook = null;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

The URL changes correctly, but the widgets remain unchanged. If I put a Button on BookDetailsScreen which calls the same callback, everything works as expected.

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the Navigator on your RouterDelegate is unchanged, you need to explicitly define a condition for handling null `_selectedBook`

```dart
Navigator(
  key: navigatorKey,
  pages: [
    if (show404)
      MaterialPage(key: ValueKey('UnknownPage'), child: UnknownScreen())
    else if (_selectedBook != null)
      BookDetailsPage(book: _selectedBook)
    else // handle _selectedBook null
      MaterialPage(
        key: ValueKey('BooksListPage'),
        child: BooksListScreen(
          books: books,
          onTapped: _handleBookTapped,
        ),
      ),
  ]
)
```